# When did egregious become something bad? (archaic was something good)

Tags: etymology

The archaic meaning of egregious is something good. Now it means the opposite.

When did this occur and is there any reasoning on why this occurred?

Comment: Have you checked any sources? There is some information here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=egregious which claims it is an ironic use from the late 16th C.

Comment: Well the literal definition of its root is *to stand out from the flock,* so it's not hard to see how this could come to be understood in a negative light.

Comment: Ah @Silenus has found a good source: according to it, egregious started off being used in the bad sense ironically. Funny how using something in mockery/jest can make its meaning evolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's up with the word "egregious"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71551/whats-up-with-the-word-egregious) Also [How do you usually interpret “egregious”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155033/) and [How does a word come to have two completely opposite meanings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/), among others.